# Hibernate Question on Sessions

Tags: java, hibernate

I am writing a web application that allows a user to get an employee's personal information and edit it (email, phone, name, etc). When I deploy the application on the server, if I try edit the employee, I can occasionally get an error saying "Hibernate session is already closed." My code for talking to the database via hibernate is below:

```
/*
 * File: EmployeeMapper.java
 */

package org.hibernate.employee;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

/**
 * This class represents the data mapper for an employee to the
 * database.
 */
public class EmployeeMapper {

    /**
     * Constructs an EmployeeMapper object.
     */
    public EmployeeMapper() {
    }

    /**
     * Finds an employee in the database by the username specified.
     * 
     * @param username the username to find
     * @return the employee if the username is in the database, null otherwise
     */
    public Employee findByUserName(String username) {
        Session session = SessionFactoryUtil.getInstance().getCurrentSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Query q = session.createQuery("from Employee e where e.username='"
                    + username + "'");
            List results = q.list();

            for (Object o : results) {
                Employee e = (Employee) o;
                return e;
            }
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
                   session.close();
            }
            return null;
    }

    /**
     * Updates the employee in the database by writing it to the database.
     * 
     * @param employee the employee to update in the database
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    public void updateEmployee(Employee employee) {
        Session session = SessionFactoryUtil.getInstance().getCurrentSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            session.update(employee);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch(RuntimeException e){
            if(tx != null){
                tx.rollback();
            }
            throw e;
        } finally {
        session.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for what I should do? If you need to post other classes or files to get more information on this program, please state what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's common to [open a session for each view](https://www.hibernate.org/43.html).

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you get that while processing your view (jsp/velocity/jsf).
Read on the [Open Session in View](https://www.hibernate.org/43.html) document which explains the problem thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

When you get that error, you're not in that code.

For example, `findByUserName` return an object.
That object has connections to other objects, that may not be initialized from the database.

- While the Session is open, if you access that non-fetched data, database queries are triggered silently to fetch the data as you access it. This is the **lazy mode**.
- Once you get out of the method, the Session is closed. Any attempt to access the lazy data will trigger the exception you mention.

---

In your example, while you think that only the above code talks to the database, there are probably outside accesses. Two solutions for your problem:

- Use the **Open-Session-In-View** pattern explained in other answers. Note that they are several heavy drawbacks associated with it, so you have to carefully weight the options.
- **Ensure all the data you need is fetched before** your business code delivers the entities to the Presentation layer. This is the approach that our last three applications have been using.

Answer (score 1):

If you using Spring in your project try 
[OpenSessionInViewInterceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewInterceptor.html)